# How to map many-to-one relationship?

Tags: java, hibernate, relationship

I have a problem with map many-to-one relationship. When I create mapper for one-to-one, that's OK.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PATIENT")
public class PatientEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String firstName;

    @OneToOne(
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            optional = false
    )
    private AddressEntity address;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "patient")
    private List<VisitEntity> visit;
```

My mapper for one-to-one relationship:

```
public final class PatientMapper {
    public static PatientTO mapToTO(final PatientEntity patientEntity)
    {
        if (patientEntity == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        final PatientTO patientTO = new PatientTO();
        patientTO.setId(patientEntity.getId());
        patientTO.setFirstName(patientEntity.getFirstName());

        final AddressTO addressTO = new AddressTO();
        addressTO.setId(patientEntity.getAddress().getId());
        addressTO.setCity(patientEntity.getAddress().getCity());

        patientTO.setAddress(addressTO);

        return patientTO;
    }

    public static PatientEntity mapToEntity(final PatientTO patientTO)
    {
        if(patientTO == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        PatientEntity patientEntity = new PatientEntity();
        patientEntity.setId(patientTO.getId());
        patientEntity.setFirstName(patientTO.getFirstName());

        AddressEntity addressEntity = new AddressEntity();
        addressEntity.setId(patientTO.getAddress().getId());
        addressEntity.setCity(patientTO.getAddress().getCity());

        patientEntity.setAddress(addressEntity);

        return patientEntity;
    }
}
```

How to build code for many-to-one relationship [private List<VisitEntity> visit]?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to map the `List<VisitEntity>` in your `PatientEntity` to `List<VisitTO>` in your `PatientTO` and vice-versa. I'm assuming you also have a `VisitMapper` that maps between `VisitEntity` and `VisitTO`.

For example:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public final class PatientMapper {
    public static PatientTO mapToTO(final PatientEntity patientEntity)
    {
        if (patientEntity == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        final PatientTO patientTO = new PatientTO();
        patientTO.setId(patientEntity.getId());
        patientTO.setFirstName(patientEntity.getFirstName());

        final AddressTO addressTO = new AddressTO();
        addressTO.setId(patientEntity.getAddress().getId());
        addressTO.setCity(patientEntity.getAddress().getCity());
        
        // Map VisitEntity list to VisitTO list
        List<VisitTO> visitTOs = patientEntity.getVisits()
            .stream()
            .map(VisitMapper::mapToTO)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
        patientTO.setVisits(visitTOs);

        patientTO.setAddress(addressTO);

        return patientTO;
    }

    public static PatientEntity mapToEntity(final PatientTO patientTO)
    {
        if(patientTO == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        PatientEntity patientEntity = new PatientEntity();
        patientEntity.setId(patientTO.getId());
        patientEntity.setFirstName(patientTO.getFirstName());

        AddressEntity addressEntity = new AddressEntity();
        addressEntity.setId(patientTO.getAddress().getId());
        addressEntity.setCity(patientTO.getAddress().getCity());
        
        // Map VisitTO list to VisitEntity list
        List<VisitEntity> visitEntities = patientTO.getVisits()
            .stream()
            .map(VisitMapper::mapToEntity)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
        patientEntity.setVisits(visitEntities);

        patientEntity.setAddress(addressEntity);

        return patientEntity;
    }
}
```

This modification assumes that you have a `VisitMapper` class with `mapToTO` and `mapToEntity` methods for `VisitEntity` and `VisitTO`. If you don't have this, you will need to create it similarly to your `AddressMapper`.

Still, remember to set the patient in each `VisitEntity` when you are mapping from `VisitTO` to `VisitEntity`, otherwise you will lose the link back to the patient.